# In Eclipse, can I view the files I currently have open in a vertical stack instead of a horizontal one?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would find it much easier if the tabs show which files are in the Editor were stacked vertically rather than horizontally.  Stacked horizontally means that you run out of room to display file names very fast and makes switching between files time consuming.

Is there an option or a plugin to display the files vertically? (Similar to navigator, but for open files instead of project files)  I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Eclipse 3.8

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> brings up an Editors dialog as shown in this screen capture:

[image]

### Eclipse 4.3

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> brings up the pop-up shown in this screen capture:

[image]

Comment: You can use `Ctrl + F6` to bring this up on older versions of Eclipse.

Comment: `Ctrl + G` doesn't work on Eclipse 4.3.0. However `Ctrl + E` or `Shift + Ctrl + E` does the trick.

Answer (score 29):

tabs can not be stacked vertically. However, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on mac) might give you some relief.

Comment: After pressing CTRL+E you can also start typing the name of the file you're looking for in the pop-up list that appears

Comment: and you can also use wildcards like * or ? when searching in the pop-up list

Answer (score 19):

With ctrl+shift+e you can open an extra window that show you the open tabs vertically.

Comment: A pity that window closes as soon we double click on the file. I wonder if someone could make it (with a plugin?) single click and stay opened, I would just make it very thin and put by the side of the editor window.

Comment: the window opened window is very handy. It shows all the open editors, several can be marked and at the bottom there's a button "close selected editors" to close all those in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 7):

EditorViewer is very good
The project is dead, but it works fine with Eclipse 3.7.  Just drop the .jar file in the dropins folder

http://sourceforge.net/projects/editorviewer/?source=dlp

Comment: Browse to `Window`, `Show View`, `General`, `EditorViewer`.

Answer (score 3):

Another command is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> not entirely like the other ones but great to switch between your two most recent tabs. And you also get a list of open tabs like the other examples.

Comment: Just keep pressing (don't release) the CTRL key and pulse F6 to jump between windows on the popup list.

Answer (score 2):

you can always drag windows over each other to tile them vertically but if you see a ">>" at the end of the tabs clicking on it gives a file list which are open.

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of, but there are some other tipps to make life a little easier:

1) Use Mylyn, which filters the Explorer-Views so only relevant files are shown there.

2) Have a look at "Extended VS Presentation" http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html . This little plugin adds some useful features to reduce waste of screenspace. With it you can hide the file extension in editor tabs or limit the size of each tab and reduce the padding. Then you can remove the X and close tabs with a middle click. Each just a small saving, but they add up.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Eclipse, there is a plugin [Open Editors](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/open-editors) which adds a view listing all open editors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not test it myself as my version of Eclipse seems to be too old.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a true relief!
https://sourceforge.net/projects/editorviewer/?source=dlp

Install dragging the "install" button from
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vertical-tab-list

to show it
"window / show view / browsing / editors list"

On its internal menu I selected too: Sort by ext+name

Now I just need a way to hide the top tabs list and it will become perfect!

Comment: Does not work with Eclipse Neon 4.5+ as it is an Eclipse 2 plugin