# How to display editor tabs on the side of the editor pane in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse Indigo (I'm on 3.7.2), is it possible to move the editor tabs from the top of the editor pane to the side of the editor pane, creating a vertical stack of tabs?  This would allow many more tabs to be seen at once.  Given my widescreen display and the large number of active files I am switching between this would be a useful configuration.  I cannot find a setting or a plugin that will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got fed up with not being able to do this and wrote an eclipse plugin. You can find it in the marketplace at: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/open-editors

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfS6J.png)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible yet. See [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=58945) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=168379)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a plugin which would allow one to do this.

This (
[In Eclipse, can I view the files I currently have open in a vertical stack instead of a horizontal one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956065/in-eclipse-can-i-view-the-files-i-currently-have-open-in-a-vertical-stack-inste)) confirms the same unfortunately.

I just searched a bit. I can see a lot of talk about having multi-line tabs, but vertical tabs don't seem to come up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Open-Editors plugin has issue

Answer (score 0):

Works well on `Windows10 + Eclipse 4.8 + OpenJDK11`. 100%

1. Have just tested. Dont forget to link your Eclipse to JDK-11
   https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini
2. Install Plugin
   https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/open-editors#comment-6750